# Django REST Framework: Choices of TimeField not valid

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a TimeField in my models.py that uses choices of the form

```
MORNING = datetime.time(4, 0)
NIGHT = datetime.time(20, 0)
TIME_CHOICES = (
    (MORNING, _('Morning')),
    (NIGHT, _('Night'))
)
time = models.TimeField(_('Time'), choices=TIME_CHOICES)
```

serializers.py

```
class VehiclePlanningSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = mymodel
```

When i create objects via django admin and set the choice to Morning it stores a proper time `"04:00:00"` in the db. When i use `raw data` in the API GUI and insert `"04:00:00"` for time it works also. But when i use the Form on the API GUI and select Morning I get the following error:

```
"time": [
    "\"4 a.m.\" is not a valid choice."
]
```

So somehow the serializer transforms the Morning choice wrongly when he gets a time(4,0). Is there a way to suppress this transformation?